# Setting up dual-boot on 1 drive and storage partitions for 2 drives

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I have a 120GB SSD and a 2TB HDD.

I want to install Windows 7 Ultimate and Linux (Ubuntu) on the SSD, split it by 60gb each or however close to evenly as possible.

Then the storage HDD I want to dedicate like 500gb to Linux and 1500gb to Windows.  I'm pretty sure the filesystems are incompatible and I'll have to do this.

I have never partitioned or formatted drives before, and this seems a little bit more complicated than what people might normally do with a dual boot with only 1 drive, I'm a little lost.

Comment: Just use GParted.  Create a 1500GB NTFS partition and the rest to any filesystem you want supported by Linux.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy, but if you know little about partitioning it is a lot of material to digest. So I am giving you a short version, you will have to fill in the details on how to do it yourself.

1. Use a live Ubuntu distro to partition your disks, with an instrument called *gparted* which you will have to install onto the live every time you boot from the live (live distros cannot be modified).
2. Choose the following partitioning scheme:

   use ms-dos -type partition table for both SSD and HDD

   partition the SSD as follows: 1 partition 120GB filesystem ntfs, one partition 116GB 
     filesystem ext4, 4GB filesystem swap;

   partition the HDD as follows: 1500GB filesystem ntfs, 500GB filesystem ext4.
3. Install Windows on the SSD.
4. Install Ubuntu on the SSD, using *custom partition*. Use the ext4 partition on SSH as */*, the swap partition on SSD as swap, the ext4 partition on HDD as /home.
5. Use grub2 to allow correct dual-boot. If it does not work, use *Ubuntu Boot-Repair* to fix it(just Google it).
6. WHen you boot Windows, instruct it to search for drive D on HDD.

Done.